# Powershell: How to incorporate if,elseif statements for adding columns into CSV file?

Tags: powershell

I'd like the following code to add the specified columns if it finds the appropriate graphics adapter in a pc.

Right now, my if/elseif statements are throwing all kinds of errors and I'm thinking its because I put it in the wrong section of the code. The columns are not being generated as how I would like for it to.

Any advice?

```
# User needs to create a txt file containing hostnames.
function ReadHostnames($initialDirectory) {   
    [void] [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('System.Windows.Forms')
    $OpenFileDialog = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog
    if ($initialDirectory) { $OpenFileDialog.initialDirectory = $initialDirectory }
    $OpenFileDialog.filter = 'All files (*.*)|*.*'
    [void] $OpenFileDialog.ShowDialog()
    return $OpenFileDialog.FileName
}

($FilePermissions = ReadHostnames C:\) 
$FilePermissions = Get-Content $FilePermissions


write-host "Please wait while gathering information..."

$counter = 0

foreach ($computernames in $FilePermissions)       

{
 Write-host "Processing $computernames ($counter/$($FilePermissions.count))" 

IF (Test-Connection -BufferSize 32 -Count 1 -ComputerName $computernames -Quiet) 
{ 
    $Computersystem = Get-WMIObject Win32_ComputerSystem -ComputerName $computernames -AsJob 
    $videocontroller = Get-WmiObject win32_videocontroller -ComputerName $computernames -AsJob
    $bioscontroller1 = Get-WmiObject win32_bios -ComputerName $computernames -AsJob
    $bioscontroller2 = Get-WmiObject -Class:Win32_ComputerSystem -ComputerName $computernames -AsJob
    $userlogon = Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_ComputerSystem -Property UserName -ComputerName $computernames

    Wait-Job -Job $Computersystem,$videocontroller,$bioscontroller -Timeout 10 | out-Null 

    $computersystem_output = Receive-Job $Computersystem
    $intelvideocontroller_output = Receive-Job $videocontroller | ? {$_.name -ilike "*Intel*"}
    $nvidiavideocontroller_output = Receive-Job $videocontroller | ? {$_.name -ilike "*NVIDIA*"}
    $AMDvideocontroller_output = Receive-Job $videocontroller | ? {$_.name -ilike "*AMD*"}
    $bioscontroller1_output = Receive-Job $bioscontroller1
    $bioscontroller2_output = Receive-Job $bioscontroller2


# Creating spreadsheet headers

    $newrow = [Pscustomobject] @{

    Host_name = $computersystem_output.name
    Model_Name = $bioscontroller2_output.Model
    Serial_Number = $bioscontroller1_output.SerialNumber
    BIOS_Version = $bioscontroller1_output.SMBIOSBIOSVersion
    Last_User_Logon = $userlogon.UserName

    If ($intelvideocontroller_output -ilike "*Intel*") 
    { Intel_Card =  $intelvideocontroller_output.name
        IntelGraphics_Version =  $intelvideocontroller_output.DriverVersion}
  
    ElseIf ($nvidiavideocontroller_output -ilike "*NVIDIA*") 
    {  Nvidia_Card = $nvidiavideocontroller_output.name
        NvidiaGraphics_Version = $nvidiavideocontroller_output.DriverVersion }

    ElseIf ( $AMDvideocontroller_output -ilike "*AMD*") 
    {  AMD_Card = $AMDvideocontroller_output.name
        AMDGraphics_Version = $AMDvideocontroller_output.DriverVersion }

    }

     $newrow | export-csv -path c:\HostnameData.csv -Append -NoTypeInformation
     Remove-Job -job $Computersystem,$videocontroller,$bioscontroller1,$bioscontroller2 -Force
     
     $counter++

    } 


Else 
{
    write-Host "The remote computer "$computernames" is Offline"
}
 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The logic would have to be wrapped inside some type of operator such as the grouping, or sub-expression operator to be allowed as the assignment of the name. A more concise solution is using a `switch` statement before your `pscustomobject` construct and having a dynamic assignment.

```
$card_type, 
$card_version = 
    switch -Wildcard ($videocontroller.Name)
    {
        '*Intel*'  { 'Intel_Card', 'IntelGraphics_Version' }
        '*NVIDIA*' { 'Nvidia_Card', 'NvidiaGraphics_Version' }
        '*AMD*'    { 'AMD_Card', 'AMDGraphics_Version' }
        $_         { 'N/A_Card', 'N/A_Version' }
    }

$newrow = [pscustomobject]@{
    Host_name       = $computersystem_output.name
    Model_Name      = $bioscontroller2_output.Model
    Serial_Number   = $bioscontroller1_output.SerialNumber
    BIOS_Version    = $bioscontroller1_output.SMBIOSBIOSVersion
    Last_User_Logon = $userlogon.UserName
    $card_type      = $videocontroller.Name
    $card_version   = $videocontroller.DriverVersion
}
```

Now the type of card gets saved to `$card_type`, and the driver version name gets saved to `$card_version`; it also accounts for cards that didn't meet that criteria and defaults to 'N/A'.

On another note, I personally don't see why you're querying the same class of `Win32_ComputerSystem` more than once while using jobs and having them wait. You are also using 2 different type of cmdlets that do the same thing when querying those classes. You should only need the first variable assignments and you'd only have to reference them once.

---

**EDIT**:
*You also can't append properties with different names to a csv that has a column already being used by a different name.*